# Google Earth Engine - variable into band range

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created a variable from two bands (Air temperature and wind speed with GDAS dataset) and I want to store the created variable in a band in the range [0.15  - 0.35]. How can I do it?

Comment: I do not understand your post. Could you perhaps share some code? Can you expand on the subject of what you are trying to achieve: you have an ee.Image with two bands and you want an ee.Image with one band, right? What do you mean by "band range"?

Comment: Also note that on https://gis.stackexchange.com we have about 10 times more GEE-related questions than on Stackoverflow.